# Why is the doc of the task not deleting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm currently working on a task manager application using Firebase and Next.js. I have implemented a functionality to delete tasks by clicking on a button, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

I tried logging the task.taskId and it corresponds with each task so that should't be the issue.

Here is my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tasks/{taskId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the code for the component responsible for rendering and deleting tasks:

```
'use client';

import { deleteDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '@/firebase/firebase';
import Task from '@/utils/types/taskTypes';

interface TaskProps {
  tasks: Task[];
}

export default function Task({ tasks }: TaskProps) {
  const handleDeleteTask = async (taskId: string) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'tasks', taskId));
      console.log('Task deleted successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting task:', error);
    }
  };

  return tasks.map((task: Task) => (
    <div
      key={task.taskId}
      className='rounded-md border-4 border-gray-300 bg-white p-3'
    >
      <div>
        <span className='mr-2 bg-zinc-300 p-1 rounded-md font-semibold'>
          {task.label}
        </span>
        <span
          className={`
                      p-1 rounded-md font-semibold
                      ${
                        task.priority === 'High'
                          ? 'bg-red-500'
                          : task.priority === 'Medium'
                          ? 'bg-yellow-500'
                          : 'bg-green-500'
                      }`}
        >
          {task.priority == null ? 'Low' : task.priority}
        </span>
      </div>
      <h2 className='mt-4 font-semibold text-xl'>{task.name}</h2>
      <p className='mt-4 text-gray-500'>
        {task.description == null
          ? 'No description provided'
          : `'${task.description}'`}
      </p>
      <div className='mt-6 border-t-2 border-gray-400 w-full p-0'>
        <button onClick={() => handleDeleteTask(task.taskId)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: If there are no error messages or similar output, it'll be hard for us to debug the problem. Since you included the security rules in your question, you seem to suspect those might be causing the problems. If so, in your code make sure you perform the same check as you rules do. So `if (getAuth().currentUser !== null)` before you call `deleteDoc`.